# SASS Compass Complie

Tags: sass, compass

Our system is using compass to compile sass files. Following the same workflow as usual today when I run compass compile there is a long pause followed by "killed" with no errors or warning.

I'm not even sure how to troubleshoot this issue. Has anyone else run into a similar problem? If so, how did you solve it?

Thank you in advance...

*update*

I have been through the code and I cannot find a pattern to it not compiling. After making a minor change it compiled successfully making another minor change it failed. Each time I believe the problem is resolved, I make a change that's very small in scope and it breaks it again... for example removing and id (#main) from a definition stops the compile... putting it back does not fix the problem... adding a comment fixes the problem... remove it and it stays fixed, until I make another change .... I've matched my braces and gone over every change made in the last 3 days... I cannot find a cause for the error, or why its not behaving consistently

Comment: According to this discussion https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1401, you have perhaps recently introduced an infinite loop into your code. Were you able to successfully compile yesterday? If so, have a look at any new code (SASS) which has been introduced.

Comment: thank you, I will give that a read over.

Comment: I rolled back my changes and I am still having the same issue... as stated in my update, I'm not getting a consistent behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If other commands on the server die with a "Killed" error message, it could be a resource issue. Check your server logs for out of memory errors.

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you :)